# Connection refused al usar cURL en hosting HostGator

Tags: php, hosting, curl

Buenas tardes estimados.

Mi problema es el siguiente, he estado haciendo pruebas par obtener datos de una API en otro sitio con cURL PHP, en mi maquina todo funciona bien obtengo los datos y los manipulo a gusto el problema es cuando lo subo a mi hosting me lanza el siguiente error

> Failed to connect to 'sitio' port 444 after 1197 ms: Connection refused.

no entiendo si en mi maquina todo funciona bien y obtengo respuesta de la api porque me sale ese error en mi hosting 'hostgator'

este es el código que estoy usando

```
$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9";

$url_API="https://Sitio.com:444/ServiceTest/Product/GetStock?Code=40";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url_API);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

$items_origin = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo($info);
```

Comment: El servidor donde está la API disponible, podría tener algún tipo de restricción de direcciones IP que pueden consumirlo?

Comment: la verdad no estoy seguro de eso, que podría hacer para validar eso

Comment: Pruebas que se me ocurren: hacer cURL de otro recurso que sea público y ver si funciona; probar eso desde otro lugar que no sea tu compu y no sea ese hosting; revisar con los dueños de ese servicio de la API para ver si tienen alguna restricción (puedes haber caído en alguna lista negra por otro usuario de hostgator dedicado al spam, por ejemplo...)

Comment: @Alfabravo acabo de hablar con los dueños del servicio y me indican que no tienen ninguna restricción, me comentan que puede que sea algún tema de permisos del hosting ya que la solicitud tarda 0ms

Comment: @Alfabravo se te ocurre otro motivo por el cual este pasando esto

Comment: Pues HostGator [tiene eso habilitado por defecto](https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/curl), entonces eso tampoco es. Prueba dejando ese `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);` usando booleano (es decir, `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);`). Más allá de eso, sería revisar el firewall en ese host, que permita conexiones salientes a ese host y puerto (probar con telnet, wget?). Probar a otros puertos en otros servicios

Comment: @Alfabravo,  El problema era que mis host no tenia habilitado el puerto 444, luego de solicitar la liberación de ese puerto a soporte todo funciono correctamente, Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.